# Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found in

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, api, soap

I've just installed Magento version 1.9.0.1, and now testing "checkout". I got the following error message. Please, someone help.

**Step 1:** Log as Customer -

http://www.studentfilmmakers.com/filmgear

**Step 2:** Select this product (or any product), and Click "Add to Cart"

http://www.studentfilmmakers.com/filmgear/index.php/magazines-c248/studentfilmmakers-magazine-digital-edition-march-2007-edition.html

**Step 3:** Fatal error message -

```
Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found in /home/education/public_html/filmgear/app/code/core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php on line 134
```

Comment: is php soap enabled?

Comment: can you please update the code of Shipping/Carrier/Fedex.php on line 134 this

Answer (score 8):

**Diagnose**

Look up the following inside your script file

```
phpinfo();
```

If you can't find `Soap Client` set to `enabled` like so:
[image: the way soap should appear in phpinfo()]

**Fix**

Do the following:

1. Locate `php.ini` in your **apache** bin folder, I.e `Apache/bin/php.ini`
2. Remove the `;` from the beginning of `extension=php_soap.dll`
3. Restart your Apache server
4. Look up your `phpinfo();` again and check if you see a similar picture to the one above
5. If you do, problem solved!

On the other hand if this doesn't solve your issue, you may want to check the [requirements for SOAP here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soap.requirements.php). Also in the comment section you can find good advice on connecting to https.

Answer (score 8):

Facing same issue on ubuntu OS + PHP7 I managed to solve this issue by running this command

```
sudo apt-get install  php7.0-soap
```

And then restart apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Hope this may help someone.

With php5.x you can you can use

```
sudo apt-get install  php5-soap
```

Answer (score 5):

you need to enable php soap client. Go to your php.ini file and find

```
extension=php_soap.dll
```

and remove semicolon(;) , restart your apache. check phpinfo() to see if soap is installed succcessfully.

Answer (score 1):

It is issue `with php soap`.i guess `php soap client is not  enable on your system`.

also you need check soap configuration on server:

```
soap path 
soap.wsdl_cache
soap.wsdl_cache_dir
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled
soap.wsdl_cache_limit
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl
```

in php.init setting

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to Haris' answer, with YUM this is

```
sudo yum install php70-soap
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too.
I'm running centos 7 minimal. 
The php-soap package was missing from php modules. 
(this yum command will work as of October 2018)

Just ran

```
yum install php-soap
```

And it fixed it. :-)

And then you have to restart apache, and flush Magento cache.

SO:

```
apachectl restart
```

and
Then go to backend Magento System -> Cache Management and mash the 'flush Magento cache' button.